# Force DataTemlate to return a specific object

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I am writing a new WPF control to draw and edit lots of shapes, say hundreds of thousands.  To do so, I want to let the user define `DataTemplate` for his data. But `LoadContent` of this specific `DataTemplate` **must** return of specific type, `IShape`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The LoadContent method of a DataTemplate returns the root element in the template.

Comment: @mm8 I want to enforce that root of this template to be of type `IShape`.

Comment: You can't enforce this. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the whole point of templates is to support plugging in *arbitrary* visual trees.  If you have a strict requirement about the composition of a template, then using templates was the wrong design choice.

Second, templates must describe a `Visual`.  If you're going to be drawing hundreds of thousands of shapes, you *will not* be able to represent them as visuals.  Visuals are quite heavy-weight

1. They participate in input hit-testing. **(!)**
2. They have all the overhead of Dependency Objects.

   1. They participate in the inheritance context.
   2. They must communicate property changes to their parent, i.e., for properties that affect layout and render.
   3. They may contain dynamic resource references, for which they must observe changes.
3. They may extend the even heavier `UIElement` or *yet even heavier* `FrameworkElement`, which would mean:

   1. They participate in layout. **(!)**
   2. Routed events get passed through them, and may be handled by them.
   3. They may be using data binding.

As an alternative, I suggest you provide an interface by which you can be fed *geometry data*, which you can freeze, share, reuse, and render efficiently.  This will allow you to stick with the lowest-level set of graphics APIs available in WPF.  But, honestly, even that may not be good enough.

One thing's for sure, though: presenting all these shapes in the [Visual Layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/visual-layer-programming) is out of the question.  I would, at minimum, implement some form of virtualization where you can efficiently locate only those shapes that are in view (quadtree or similar?), render only the geometry in view (with clipping), and use Cached Composition to avoid constantly redrawing; re-tessellating; and performing per-primitive antialiasing on the geometry if nothing has actually changed.

Comment: Upvoted. The performance considerations are another aspect of this that I didn't cover in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `LoadContent` method of a `DataTemplate` returns the root element of the content of the template. So it will only return an `IShape` if the user (consumer) has acually defined an `IShape` as the root element in the template.

But you can't really force the consumer of your class to set a property of type `DataTemplate` to a `DataTemplate` that is guaranteed to include an `IShape`. The consumer might as well set the property to a `DataTemplate` that contains only, let's say, a `Button`.

What you can do is to throw an `InvalidOperationException`, at *runtime*, in your class if the `LoadContent` method returns anything else than an `IShape`. You can't make any guarantees at compile-time though. But this is how `DataTemplates` work.

Maybe you should consider letting the user set an `IShape` property instead of a `DataTemplate` property. You can let `IShape` (or `Shape`) be some kind of `ContentControl` or `UserControl`.

After all, a `DataTemplate` is a *template* that may contain any `UIElement`.